# Fetch records from ir.attachment with domain not working

Tags: python, odoo-14

i have written a Controller and write line as

`attachments_items = request.env["ir.attachment"].sudo().search([])`
its working and return all records but when i use with domain as

```
attachments_items = request.env["ir.attachment"].sudo().search([('res_model', '=', 'res.partner'), ('res_id', '=', data.get('res_id'))])
```

its not working and return null. Please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attachment [_search](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py#L482-L488) method was overridden and if you do not specifically add the `res_field` to the search domain, Odoo will automatically add:

```
('res_field', '=', False)
```

It is used to discard binary fields attachments

In the first search query, it will return all attachments, in the second it will return specific partner attachments, and in both cases, attachments are not related to binary fields.

Odoo returned an empty record set because there is no attachments for that partner (which are not binary field attachment).

If you want to include specific binary field attachments, you can add the resource field name to the domain

***Example:***

```
('res_field', '=', 'image_128')
```

If you want to include all field attachments, use the following:

```
('res_field', '!=', False)
```

***Example***

Using a controller to download partner attachments as a ZIP file:

```py
class DownloadZipFile(http.Controller):
    @http.route("/download_attachments/", type="http", auth="user", website=True)
    def download_attachments_vendor_routes(self, **data):
        attachments_items = request.env["ir.attachment"].search(
            [("res_id", "=", data.get('res_id')),
             ('res_model', '=', 'res.partner'),
             ('res_field', '!=', False)])

        in_memory = BytesIO()
        zip_archive = ZipFile(in_memory, "w")

        for attachment in attachments_items:
            ext = '.' + attachment.mimetype.split('/')[1]
            zip_archive.writestr(f"{attachment.name}{ext}", base64.b64decode(attachment.datas))

        zip_archive.close()
        res = http.send_file(in_memory, filename="attachments.zip", as_attachment=True)
        return res
```

*I used the same expression in [Binary](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py#L1668) controller to get the file extension*

***EDIT:***

Go to `Settings` and scroll to the bottom then click `Activate the developer mode`.

Go to `Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Attachments`, click the debug button on the top right then `Edit Action` and change the domain to:

```
[("res_id", "=", {Partner ID}), ('res_model', '=', 'res.partner'), ('res_field', '!=', False)]
```

The partner attachments should be visible, if there is no attachment, it means that there are no attachments in the database.

*Replace `{Partner ID}` with the record id you try to download the zip file*

Comment: I have checked at **Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Attachments**
there is no data of model res.partner and type binary.

But in pgAdmin i can seen data

Comment: i have used as
`('res_field', 'in', ('file_siup', 'surat_dirjen_ahu'))`
Yes its working now